# cant do npm install - Macro definition of snprintf conflicts

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm trying to start my heroku nodejs application at brand new computer. I don't have any problems with this application at older computer, but here I'm receiving:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\OEM\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\programowanie\naszatrasa\node_modules\mmmagic
gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

previous logs contain logs such as:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1927): fatal error C1189: #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration (compiling sourc
e file ..\..\..\deps\libmagic\src\apprentice.c) [C:\programowanie\naszatrasa\node_modules\mmmagic\build\deps\libmagic\libmagic.vcxproj]
```

I have tried previous versions of npm and node but had problems with node-gyp and Visual Studio 2015 (which I have installed)